# Ruby Rails: Should I use boolean true or :true?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, symbols, gitlab-ce

Ruby Rails: Should I use boolean `true` or `:true`? For example in GitLab config file `data/gitlab-rails/etc/smtp_settings.rb`:

[image: GitLab rb file]

I guess it is a minor problem - but anyways - interesting?!

---

BTW: When you want to disable authentication: Just comment or remove the line `gitlab_rails['smtp_authentication'] = false` in your `docker-compose.yml` file to prevent error `gitlab smtp ArgumentError (wrong authentication type false)`. GitLab 13.5.4-ce.0 can't handle this line - you have to remove it. Do the same for the credentials user_name and password: https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/omnibus-gitlab/-/issues/2427

Comment: Depends on what the consumer expects--there's no generic answer. For example, whatever `authentication` is might use `:false` to indicate an implementation, not a boolean value.

Comment: I thought - as a noob - that `:false` is a symbol and `false` is an object. So in this specific case it would make no difference. But I wonder why I don't find a fast answer on Google - so I asked here.

Comment: Symbol/object is correct (although `:false` is not a "boolean with a symbol", it's just a symbol). What I'm saying is that which to use depends entirely on what is *expected*, e.g., the value of `authentication` might be used to instantiate a class, not as an on/off indicator. Which to use is entirely dependent on context.